# Method call (with implicit parameters) without parenthesis in scala

Tags: scala, function

I'm trying to understand where implicit parameters come from. Here is the simple demonstration of generic type constraint implicit resolution:

```
class ImplicitTypeConstraint[+T](val t : T) {
    def doSome1(implicit ev: T <:< Int) = println("Int value = " + ev(t))
    def doSome2(implicit ev: T <:< Int, u : Unit) = println("Int value = " + ev(t))
    def doSome3(u : Unit)(implicit ev: T <:< Int) = println("Int value = " + ev(t))
}
```

Now I tried this

```
val itc = new ImplicitTypeConstraint(10)
itc.doSome1    //compiles fine
itc.doSome1()  //compile error, Cannot resolve reference doSome1 with such signature

itc.doSome2    //compile error, not enough arguments for method doSome2
itc.doSome2()  //compile error, Cannot resolve reference doSome2 with such signature

itc.doSome3    //compile error, Cannot resolve reference doSome3 with such signature
itc.doSome3()  //compiles fine
```

The question is, what is the difference between the signatures of `doSome1` and `doSome2`? I came from Java and I thought, that `foo()` will call a function which has no ***explicit*** parameters, but it seems that it looks for a function with one parameter of type `Unit`.

***UPD***: Itellij didn't show the error before I build the project explicitly. Both `doSome2()` and `doSome2` refuses to compile.

Comment: *that foo() will call a function which has no explicit parameters.* What is `foo()` here? I'm not too sure what your question is.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov there's no foo here. I talked about any function `foo` with no parameters. I said that if a method `foo` is defined with no explicit parameters, `foo()` will call it.

Comment: Unless `foo` is declared without parenthesis, and then it won't compile. `Some1` requires no explicit parameters, where `Some2` does. I'm not sure what confuses you about that?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Well, foo doesn't matter here. It was just an example :). I'm mostly concerned of how to explain the behavior with `doSomeX, X = 1, 2, 3`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov `doSome3` requires as well, nevertheless `doSome3()` compiles fine, whereas `doSome2()` does not.

Comment: `Some1` requires no explicit parameters. `Some2` and `Some3` require one explicit parameter. You're concerned with how the compiler picks which?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Maybe I was not quite clear about that. I was confused by  that `doSome2()` refuses to compile, `doSome3()` compiles fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f()` calls a method with an empty parameter list (and possibly with implicit parameters after this list). Neither `doSome1` nor `doSome2` have an empty parameter list, so of course `itc.doSome1()` and `itc.doSome2()` don't compile. `itc.doSome` compiles because it calls the function with no parameter list, and implicit parameters are inserted. `itc.doSome2` doesn't compile because there is no `implicit Unit` in scope.

In `itc.doSome3()`, `()` is the value of type `Unit`, not the method call parentheses. So it's actually `itc.doSome3(())`. The compiler should give a warning about this:

```
Warning:(15, 13) Adaptation of argument list by inserting () has been deprecated: this is unlikely to be what you want.
        signature: ImplicitTypeConstraint.doSome3(u: Unit)(implicit ev: <:<[T,Int]): Unit
  given arguments: <none>
 after adaptation: ImplicitTypeConstraint.doSome3((): Unit)
itc.doSome3();//
           ^
```

Comment: But why did they do a distinction between functions with empty-parameter list and functions with no-parameters? Was there a reason for that?

Comment: The convention is that an empty parameter list indicates the method has side-effects, no parameters are used for methods which don't (e.g. field/lazy val getters, but not only).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: i think there are some typos. Probably you meant doSome1 instead of doSome in a couple of places. There is no doSome method.

Comment: @Samar Thanks, fixed.

Comment: So, how to invoke `doSome2` then? As I found, the `()` literal represents the unique value of `Unit`. I thought we could just omit supplying implicit parameters and therefore `doSome2(())` should have compiled. Compiler gives an error `Unspecified value for parameter u` though. But I specified it as `()`. Couldn't you explain it?

Comment: You are specifying it in the wrong place: as the first argument, not the second. You can invoke it as `implicit val u: Unit = (); doSome2`, or `doSome2(implicitly[Int <:< Int], ())`. But having a `Unit` parameter doesn't make much sense in real code, and an `implicit` `Unit` parameter even less so.

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is, there needs to be a **type** that can be viewed as `Int` in the implicit scope. You can provide that yourself as

`implicit val intView = implicitly[Int <:< Int]`

```
val itc = new ImplicitTypeConstraint(10)
itc.doSome1
```

And then you can define `doSome1` as follows:

```
class ImplicitTypeConstraint[+T](val t : T) {
    def doSome1()(implicit ev: T <:< Int) = println("Int value = " + ev(t))
    def doSome2(implicit ev: T <:< Int, u : Unit) = println("Int value = " + ev(t))
    def doSome3(u : Unit)(implicit ev: T <:< Int) = println("Int value = " + ev(t))
}
```

Then both:

```
itc.doSome1    //compiles fine
itc.doSome1()  // compiles fine too
```

But to call `doSome2`

```
itc.doSome2()                 //compiles fine
itc.doSome2(intView, println) // implicit won't work here
```

Calling `doSome3`. This is the usual/correct way to use implicits in methods. You better [curry](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/30/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-11-currying-and-partially-applied-functions.html) it like that.

```
itc.doSome3(println) // compiles fine
```